# Sacrifice a blocking creature or sacrifice an attacking creature

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I want to use Ayli, Eternal Pilgrim in my black and white aggro deck. Would it be possible if someone attacked me and I blocked with a less stronger creature causing it to die but can I activate Ayli, Eternal Pilgrims ability at this same time so a I get something out of it? I’m also asking the same thing about if I used one of my creatures to attack and it got blocked by a higher creature or got countered by a spell there it would die but can I use the sacrifice ability at the same time?

Comment: Check out this question for more info: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/4332/15514 . Short answer, you can either have the creature deal *and* receive damage then die, **or** you can sacrifice it Ayli, not both.

Comment: Also note that a creature on the battlefield can't get "countered" because it's not a spell. It can be confusing because the same card represents a few different things: when you cast it from your hand it's a spell that is summoning a creature, but once it's on the field it *is* the creature.